# Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array()

Tags: php, html, datetime, pdo, timezone

I'm trying to make a system that takes a users default timezone, and then converts it to that, from the server timezone.  This is for the IP logs any user can view on my site. I'm totally stumped...

```
    <?php
    $SQLGetIP = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `loginip` WHERE `username` = :username ORDER BY `loginip`.`date` DESC");
    $SQLGetIP -> execute(array(':username' => $_SESSION['username']));
        $getInfo = $SQLGetIP->fetch_array();

    $query = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query -> execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['id']));
        $data = $query->fetch_array();


    $dt1 = $getInfo['date'];
    $tz = $data['timezone'];
    $dt = new DateTime("@".$dt1."");
    $dt -> setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz));

    $IP = $getInfo['logged'];
    $Date = $dt->format('F d, Y - h:i:s A');

        echo '<tr><td>'.$IP.'</td><td>'.$Date.'</td></tr>';

    ?>
```

Comment: You have two call to fetch_array(). Which one is causing it?

Comment: Why is that error occurring?  It is supposed to show the date in the users timezone, though it doesn't. My PHP error log showed [27-Sep-2014 06:31:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array() in /home/public_html/iplogs.php on line 84

Comment: Which line is 84 here?

Comment: $getInfo = $SQLGetIP->fetch_array();
Is line 84.

Comment: @PaulCrovella  That seemed to fix that error, but now I am getting this one: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character' On line 92  Which is:     $dt = new DateTime("@".$dt1."");

Comment: @AustinWilley remove `@` from datetime function

Answer (score 2):

`$result = $sth->fetch(fetch_style);`

**fetch_style can be :**

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default)

PDO::FETCH_BOUND

PDO::FETCH_CLASS

PDO::FETCH_INTO

PDO::FETCH_LAZY

PDO::FETCH_NAMED:

PDO::FETCH_NUM

PDO::FETCH_OB
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt it be:

```
$resultset = $query -> execute(array(':id' => $_SESSION['id']));
$data = $resultset->fetch_array();
```

Comment: No. It is fine to call execute without any assignment.